# Css3 animation glitch error Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this sidebar menu with css and bootstrap:
(please reduce size of the iframe to see the menu button)

http://jsfiddle.net/s8hts3v7/11/

If you toggle the sidebar menu you can detect some glitch and the sidebar is not smoothing in the animation.

This bad effect or glitch error it is even more detectable with Firefox.

The classes that I used for this menu are:

```
/*sidebar nav*/
.navbar-toggle {
    background: #CFD8DC;
    color: #666;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: #666;
    width: 17px;
    height: 3px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    -webkit-transition-property: background,top,right,bottom,left;
    transition-property: background,top,right,bottom,left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s,0,0,0,0;
    transition-duration: .5s,0,0,0,0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    transition-delay: 0;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.active {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#sidebar-menu {
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
  }

  .sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-nav li {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-indent: 20px;
  }

  .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999999;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: white;
    text-indent: initial;
    padding-left: 12px;
  }
  .sidebar-brand img {
    width: 134px;
  }
  .sidebar-brand #menu-close {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 200;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
  }

  #sidebar-wrapper.active #sidebar-menu {
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  }

  .toggle {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You really mean appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Comment or remove `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` on `#sidebar-wrapper` (it is overlaying `body` when toggled):

**[Link to your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/s8hts3v7/14/)**

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  });
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: #E9E9E9 !important;
}

/*sidebar nav*/

.navbar-toggle {
  background: #CFD8DC !important;
  color: #666 !important;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #666 !important;
  width: 17px !important;
  height: 3px !important;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  /* background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  -webkit-transition-property: background, top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: background, top, right, bottom, left;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  transition-duration: .5s, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#sidebar-menu {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: white;
  text-indent: initial;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.sidebar-brand img {
  width: 134px;
}

.sidebar-brand #menu-close {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 200;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active #sidebar-menu {
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.toggle {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body id="fotieditor">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button id="menu-toggle" type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div id="sidebar-menu">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <i id="menu-close" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://rp-static.com/www_mantaspersonalizadas/svg/mantas-personalizadas.svg" alt=""></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this no resolve anything, simply the glitch is not seen because there is white background.

Comment: And also I miss the style of the background black

Comment: It does solve it, look above, I added a picture. Embed snippet is getting background white, probably an override by bootstrap stylesheet. This was tested on all browsers on your own snippet, has nothing to do with being white or any color.

Comment: Can you solve it in my jsfiddle?, the glitch persists in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Added above, the solution is exactly the same.

Comment: Added a few `!important` as well to preserve the original colors on the embed snippet, also you have screenshots of both chrome and firefox.